# How to inherit static generic methods in Typescript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I can't compile Typescript code because the compiler does not seem to understand the inheritance between my classes.

When I try to compile, I run into this error

`Property 'create' does not exist on type 'new () => T'.`

```
export abstract class Resource {

    // creates a new resource and returns it
    static async create<T>(this: { new(): T }, resource: T): Promise<T> {
      const resource = ... // using "this"
      return resource;
    }

}
```

```
export abstract class ContainerResource extends Resource {

  static async addToContainer<T>(this: { new(): T }, resource: T, containerId: string): Promise<T> {
    r = await this.create(resource); // Property 'create' does not exist on type 'new () => T'.

    // do some stuff

    return r;
  }

}
```

I except this code to compile. It does not work even with `addToContainer<T extends Resource>` :(

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a static method through "this". That's always wrong. Try replacing "this" with "Resource"

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to call the create function on Resource directly. I would like to call it on the generic type T represented by "this". It is because I use "this" in the create function.

I could call "this" any name I want it does not matter